# Mouseover thumbnail to view large image Without javascript

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a CSS option that will allow me to mouseover a thumbnail image to replace the "large" image. The trick here is using the anchor href from the thumbnail link as the large image source.

Below code works only with javascript but I need to be done it with CSS and without javascript.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-1">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=1">
</div>


<div id="thumbs" class="mouseover">
    <a class="thumb-image-1" id="thumb_1" href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=1" title="1"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/000/fff&text=1" alt="image 1"/></a>
    <a class="thumb-image-1" id="thumb_2" href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=2" title="2"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/000/fff&text=2" alt="image 1"/></a>
    <a class="thumb-image-1"id="thumb_3" href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=3" title="3"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/000/fff&text=3" alt="image 1"/></a>
</div>

... 

<div class="image-2">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/f00/fff&text=2">
</div>

<div id="thumbs" class="mouseover">
    <a class="thumb-image-2" id="thumb_1" href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/f00/fff&text=1" title="1"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/f00/fff&text=1" alt="image 1"/></a>
    <a class="thumb-image-2" id="thumb_2" href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/f00/fff&text=2" title="2"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/f00/fff&text=2" alt="image 1"/></a>
    <a class="thumb-image-2" id="thumb_3" href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/f00/fff&text=3" title="3"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/f00/fff&text=3" alt="image 1"/></a>
</div>

<script>

$(function() {

    $(".mouseover a").mouseover(function(){
        var src=$(this).attr('href');
        var classs=$(this).attr('class');
        classs=classs.substr(6);        
        $('.'+classs).find('img').attr('src',src);

    })

})
</script>
```

Need your kind assistant

Comment: what did you try so far ? we only accept questions that show efforts in a direction to a solution, not only starting pionts

Comment: i do not find anything that's why i have nothing to show you.

Comment: you did not attempt a css solution, which is why the question as it stands, goes against the questions policy.

what you should do is attempt a css solution, and post a question when you're stuck

Comment: I am stuck, because i have no clue how to convert javascript code to css

Comment: there is no way to convert javascript to css, I'll flag the question to be closed
please read more on the topic of HTML/CSS/JS, and learn to use CSS and what it does stand for.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference

Answer (score 0):

You can use "transform: scale()"

```css
.mouseover img{
  transition: transform 1s;

}

.mouseover img:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="thumbs" class="mouseover">
    <a class="thumb-image-1" id="thumb_1" href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=1" title="1"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/000/fff&text=1" alt="image 1"/></a>
    <a class="thumb-image-1" id="thumb_2" href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=2" title="2"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/000/fff&text=2" alt="image 1"/></a>
    <a class="thumb-image-1"id="thumb_3" href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=3" title="3"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/000/fff&text=3" alt="image 1"/></a>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Or, if you want to change the imge instead to use "scale()", you can change the HTML structure like this:

```css
.mouseover .thumb-image:hover .small {
    display: none;
}
.mouseover .thumb-image:hover .big {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
.display-none {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="thumbs" class="mouseover">
        <a class="thumb-image thumb-image-1" id="thumb_1" title="1">
            <img class="small" src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/000/fff&text=1" alt="image 1"/>
            <img class="big display-none" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=1" alt="image 1"/>
        </a>
        <a class="thumb-image thumb-image-1" id="thumb_2" title="2">
            <img class="small" src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/000/fff&text=2" alt="image 1"/>
            <img  class="big display-none" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=2" alt="image 1"/>
        </a>
        <a class="thumb-image thumb-image-1"id="thumb_3" title="3">
            <img class="small" src="http://dummyimage.com/60x40/000/fff&text=3" alt="image 1"/>
            <img  class="big display-none" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=3" alt="image 1"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```